# mysterious unwanted space got added in Text view

Tags: swift, swiftui

It's simpler to just read the code and see the end result in the image, my question is why is ***Actuation Force*** and ***Bottom-out Force*** not aligned with the text views above them? In ***Actuation Force*** text view, there seems to be some mysterious padding added to its left while ***Bottom-out Force*** does not have it?

[image]

```
VStack {
    VStack {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                Text("**Pre-travel Distance**")
                Text("how far down the key must be pressed for it to actuate")
            }
            .frame(width: 250)
            .background(.red)
            SwitchPropertyCircularView(upperBoundValue: theSwitch.preTravelDistance!, unit: "mm")
        }
        .background(.blue)

        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                Text("**Total Travel Distance**")
                Text("how far down the key must be pressed for it to bottom out")
            }
            .frame(width: 250)
            .background(.red)
            SwitchPropertyCircularView(upperBoundValue: theSwitch.totalTravelDistance!, unit: "mm")
        }
        .background(.blue)
    }
    .frame(width: 380)
    .background(Color.gray)

    VStack {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                Text("**Actuation Force**")
                Text("the force needed to register a keypress")
            }
            .frame(width: 250)
            .background(.red)
            SwitchPropertyCircularView(upperBoundValue: Double(theSwitch.actuationForce!), unit: "gf")
        }
        .background(.blue)

        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                Text("**Bottom-out Force**")
                Text("the force needed for a switch to bottom out")
            }
            .frame(width: 250)
            .background(.red)
            SwitchPropertyCircularView(upperBoundValue: Double(theSwitch.bottomOutForce!), unit: "gf")
        }
        .background(.blue)
    }
    .frame(width: 380)
    .background(Color.gray)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On "Bottom-out Force," it looks like the first line is wide enough before it wraps words that it pushes the `Text` width to the maximum width of the view. On the others, it gets wrapped with shorter line lengths, and then ends up adding padding to center the text within the view.

You can fix this by adding a `.leading` alignment to your `VStack`. For example:

```
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
  Text("**Actuation Force**")
  Text("the force needed to register a keypress")
}
.frame(width: 250, alignment: .leading) //<-- Here
```

Repeat for each `VStack` that shares the same qualities.